# Can I use Carbon Datasource in dss for work in WSO2 Micro Integrator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I start wso2ei micro integrator profile and deploy carbonapp with
carbon datasource in dbs file. Then I get nullpointer error in get datasource in log.

If I specify jdbc datasource in dbs - it all ok.

Can I use carbon datasource in dbs for micro integrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carbon datasources feature is not shipped with micro integrator.  When a carbon datasource is created it saves in the registry in the default ESB profile. As all the registry related features are removed from the micro integrator, it is not available. Instead you can define the datasource in line in the dataservice it self.